# Trying to save a manual DataTable to my SQL Server CE table

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

In my database, I have a table with a primary key identity column, and 3 other columns as follows.

I want to manually create a `DataTable` and save it to my SQL Server CE database. Can anyone help me tweak my code please?

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("MyTable1");
table1.Columns.Add("LastName");
table1.Columns.Add("FirstName");
table1.Columns.Add("SortColumn");
table1.Rows.Add("Doe", "John", 1);
table1.Rows.Add("Doe", "Mary", 2);

DataSet ds = new DataSet("notCritical1");
ds.Tables.Add(table1);

using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(TestClickOnceApp.classes.ClassDatabase.m_connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select * from MyTable1", con);
    da.Fill(ds, "MyTable1");
    da.Update(ds, "MyTable1");
}
```

Comment: DataAdapters are used for binding control (like DataGrid) values to DataSets. Your example has no controls; if you are not binding to controls you do not need a DataAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't SqlCompact to test, but I presume you could write code like this

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))   
{   
    con.Open();   
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("Select * from MyTable1 Where 1=0", con);
    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    SqlCeCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Update(table1);
}
```

no need to use a dataset

More details on the base class method **DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable t)** can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do...as I wanted to manually loop through and manipulate the data: MANY THANKS!

Comment: Haha, I tried to Upvote, but I guess I'm too new and don't have any credibility yet

Comment: @user1366569 yes, you need at least a [15 reps to upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-is-15-reputation-required-to-upvote).

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a dataset at all.  Just use an `INSERT` to put records in the database.  It should look something like this:

```
using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString)
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCeCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO <TableName> LastName, FirstName, SortColumn VALUES 'Doe', 'John', '1'";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you try it wrong. you have to perform a SQL statement. the DataTable / DataSet does NOT represent the database itself.
maybe this could help you [link](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/26/create-a-table-in-sql-server-compact-edition-with-c/)